# jhipster: how to avoid database update when running in PROD mode?

Tags: java, jhipster

When I run my jhipster app in production mode (spring.profiles.active=prod) the database update is always executed. I need to avoid this behaviour because organizational policies require DB updates to be run manually by the DBA.

Is it possible?

**UPDATE with answer:**
Yes, it is possible. The way to do it is exactly what @julien-dubois said: in the application-prod.yml file add the following line:

```
liquibase.enabled: false
```

Warning, the application-prod.yml generated by jhipster already contains some liquibase configuration

```
liquibase:
    context: prod
```

But do not add the "enabled" entry under that "liquibase" entry because it is ignored. You should add a new root level entry:

```
liquibase.enabled: false
liquibase:
    context: prod
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [common Spring Boot property](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html)

In your `application-prod.yml` you need to set `liquibase.enabled=false`

Comment: Thanks, but that is not working for me. Let me explain the test I am doing. I created my war and place it in a directory next to my application-prod.properties with the following content.  

    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb  
    spring.datasource.username=myuser  
    spring.datasource.password=myuser  
    liquibase.enabled=false  

When I run my app in prod using an empty database (no tables at all) I would expect the application to fail, but instead of that all tables are created (domain tables and also liquibase tables).

any idea?

Comment: Why don't you use our configuration file? Your other file is probably not picked up.

Comment: The config provided by jhipster is yml and we always use .properties files because we have other stuff that is no jhipster-based. 

But the .properties file I am using is being picked up, because the connection to the database is working fine.

Comment: OK, but then that's not a JHipster issue... If you are using another configuration file, then that's your issue!

Comment: ok, I switched to yml and I found the issue. I am updating the initial question with the answer and the explanation.